# Running Laravel 5 project with DB_HOST=localhost and 127.0.0.1 PDOException

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5 on Windows 10, VB, homestead and I am still new, I've just started learning Laravel.

When I run my project in Chrome using DB_HOST=127.0.0.1 in .env file I get this error message:
PDOException in Connector.php line 55:
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

and when I change DB_HOST to localhost everything is fine except when I am using tinker (php artisan tinker). I get this message:
PDOException with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory'

Database works with DB_HOST=localhost and tinker DB_HOST=127.0.0.1

So, I can't use both at the same time, everytime I must change DB_HOST in .env file from localhost to 127.0.0.1

What can I do to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Homestead, your DB_HOST should be set to localhost.

The reason why in such case artisan (migrate) cannot connect to database is because you are not executing the commands inside your virtual machine.

To do it the right way connect to your vm using:

```
vagrant ssh
```

and once logged in, continue as you'd normally.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I am also using WAMP, and when I connect to my vm and type php artisan or php artisan tinker etc. (inside my project, vagrant/Code/Laravel) I get an error:
The program 'php' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install php5-cli